# Collection Select with Devise (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, has-many-through

I am working on an application where we have `users` and `projects`. Each user can manage a project. In any case, I'd like the users to define / choose their project at `sign up`. Users and projects are linked with a `has many through` association.

I've added this code to the sign up form using `form_for`.

```
<%= f.collection_select :project_ids, @projects, :id, :project_name, {}, { :multiple => false } %>
```

**In Development:** It works perfectly!

**In Production:** It breaks, I get "We're sorry, but something went wrong." from Heroku and the user is not created.

The logs don't give a reason why this fails.

```
2013-11-27T20:40:11.087603+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 66.44.22.241 at      2013-11-27 20:40:11 +0000
2013-11-27T20:40:13.443773+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-11-27T20:40:13.443773+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to tests@email.com (894ms)
2013-11-27T20:40:13.935915+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.44.22.241 at 2013-11-27 20:40:13 +0000
```

When I remove the association attribute,sign in works and the log looks the same (to me, at least).

```
2013-11-27T20:45:21.122286+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 66.44.22.241 at   2013-11-27 20:45:21 +0000
2013-11-27T20:45:22.402149+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-11-27T20:45:22.402149+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to tests@email.com (714ms)
2013-11-27T20:45:23.116820+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.44.22.241 at 2013-11-27 20:45:23 +0000
```

My devise override:

```
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
resource = @user

if resource.save
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    flash[:notice] = "Signed up successsfully."
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Signed up successsfully."
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  respond_with resource
end
end
```

Comment: What are the error messages you find when running "heroku logs"

Answer (score 1):

The likely issue is that an after_save that comes after the devise one is rolling back the save transaction after devise has sent the email. Move the devise statement toward the bottom if the user model and see what interesting things surface.

Comment: The error was on this line: `respond_with resource`
The problem wasn't receiving the error, it was that the user was not being created. I changed respond_to resource to `redirect_to root_path`, that stops the app from giving an error, but the user is not created.

Comment: I changed the heroku logs output to show what happens. I will add another for a successful sign when i remove the association attribute.

Comment: So it's saying that it sent an email to the user, but didn't actually create the user?

Comment: Yes -- and I actually get the email (to the address that I really use). When I click the confirm, it says invalid. confirmation token is invalid.

Comment: So something downstream is causing the transaction to roll back after the confirmation email is sent. Downstream after_save. In the user model, is the devise statement below the associations or other callbacks? These all add callbacks in order.

Comment: Yes, have you ever heard of something like this?

Comment: Yes. You need to find out which after_save is returning false, including those added by associations and other plugins.

Comment: All of the `after_create` callbacks that were in the application have been commented out. Will check though.

The issue again -- is that it works when I do a traditional save, but adding the association causes it to break in production.

Comment: And is there an adter_save on any associated models? What happens in the console when you build the same object and attempt to save it?

Comment: No after_saves. I'm stripping everything down little by little now -- jus cleared the devise registrations controller. Still rolled back (even in console).

Comment: Are the dev and production databases the same? What happens when you run locally in production environment?